# Overflow scroll Y in children block does not work with max-height property in parent block

Tags: html, css

I get confused how CSS worked. Please, help me understand deep mechanics.

Task is simple:

1. **Block1** have fixed height;
2. **Block2** have semi-adaptive height (he can be small as content, but not bigger then max-height, if there is to much content );
3. **Block3** have 3 parts:

   ***_Header***. Fixed height

   ***_Main***. Semi-adaptive height

   ***_Footer***. Fixed height
4. "***Block3_Main***" must turn on Y scroll inside itself when it have to much content

Question is: why overflow Y scroll in block3_main does not work if block2 have "max-height" property instead of "height"? And, at the same time (!), in same situation (!), why does overflow X scroll work FINE with "max-width" instead of "width" as property of block 2?

Full sample is here: https://codepen.io/Cosmos07/pen/OJxpdam

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="block1">
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="block3_Header">
      <div>
        Header
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block3_Main">
      <div>
        This block must have Y scroll, when there is to much content, right here >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> <br>
        *Note: if you do not see any scrolls make page shorter* <br>
        But there is only hole page scroll, not block3_Main scroll <br>
        And this is happend because of "max-height" CSS rule in .block2 <br>
        If change "max-height" to "height" problem will be fixed <br>
        Question is "Why does it work this way?" <br>
        But! In the same situation X scroll work FINE! Right here VVVVV<br>This block must have Y scroll, when there is to much content, right here >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> <br>
        *Note: if you do not see any scrolls make page shorter* <br>
        But there is only hole page scroll, not block3_Main scroll <br>
        And this is happend because of "max-height" CSS rule in .block2 <br>
        If change "max-height" to "height" problem will be fixed <br>
        Question is "Why does it work this way?" <br>
        But! In the same situation X scroll work FINE! Right here VVVVV<br>
        This block must have Y scroll, when there is to much content, right here >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> <br>
        *Note: if you do not see any scrolls make page shorter* <br>
        But there is only hole page scroll, not block3_Main scroll <br>
        And this is happend because of "max-height" CSS rule in .block2 <br>
        If change "max-height" to "height" problem will be fixed <br>
        Question is "Why does it work this way?" <br>
        But! In the same situation X scroll work FINE! Right here VVVVV<br>
        This block must have Y scroll, when there is to much content, right here >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> <br>
        *Note: if you do not see any scrolls make page shorter* <br>
        But there is only hole page scroll, not block3_Main scroll <br>
        And this is happend because of "max-height" CSS rule in .block2 <br>
        If change "max-height" to "height" problem will be fixed <br>
        Question is "Why does it work this way?" <br>
        But! In the same situation X scroll work FINE! Right here VVVVV<br>
        This block must have Y scroll, when there is to much content, right here >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> <br>
        *Note: if you do not see any scrolls make page shorter* <br>
        But there is only hole page scroll, not block3_Main scroll <br>
        And this is happend because of "max-height" CSS rule in .block2 <br>
        If change "max-height" to "height" problem will be fixed <br>
        Question is "Why does it work this way?" <br>
        But! In the same situation X scroll work FINE! Right here VVVVV<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block3_Footer">
      <div>
        Footer
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block2 {
  max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 1040px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px lightgray;
}

.block3_Header {
  height: 20px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block3_Main {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
  
  overflow: auto;
  
  padding: 10px;
}

.block3_Footer {
  height: 20px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The height for block 3 main isn't working properly, if you set that to a fixed number you can see it working. Maybe investigate that and see what's going on. Probably also change block2 width so that it is actually visible in the demonstration

Comment: Feels like 100% in block3_main height formula do not get any number from Block2 as his parent. But in same formula width of Block3_main get 100% from his parent and calc everything right. I do not know hot to see height of Block3_main real calculation formula in process.